# Remap a key only when in final line of a file

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement

I want to remap a key, but I want the mapping to be active only when I'm in the last line of my file. Is there a simple way to do this? I would also like to do a similar thing when I'm in the first line, but that is not essential to me at the moment.

My specific use case is that I want to remap `j` to `<C-E>` when I'm in the final line, but I also want to know if this is possible for curiosity's sake.

Comment: you can make use of expression mappings for this

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt you mean as in [ref](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_2)#Expression_maps) ? I didn't know this was a possibility but it looks promising. Can I remap a key to itself then? Do you think you can sketch a function that does something like what I'm looking for? I'm not super familiar with vimscript, but if there is an api to get the current line this should be a simple if statement right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Expression mappings](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap-expression) allow you to map to a dynamic `rhs`:

Try this:

```
:nnoremap <expr> j line('.') == line('$') ? '<C-E>' : 'j'
```

This makes use of a [`ternary`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr1) if-then-else expression  to map to `<C-E>` on the last line or `j` otherwise.